# How to use one of the current document field as coordinates in $geoIntersects query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, gis, geospatial

I'm trying to create an aggregation pipeline to intersect some shapes with some others. a simplified pipeline is like this:

```
[
   {
    '$match': {
      'loc.type': {
        '$eq': 'Polygon'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'cor': [
        [
          -11.337890625, 56.31653672211301
        ], [
          13.1396484375, 42.8115217450979
        ]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'loc': {
        '$geoIntersects': {
          '$geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString', 
            'coordinates': '$cor'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

At the first step, I selected every polygon shape from a collection, in the next stage added some coordinates to it, and at the end match the polygon with the shape added in stage 2.
the problem is in stage 3, I can't fill the `coordinates` field with the `cor` field created in stage 2.

the error I get is: `GeoJSON coordinates must be an array of coordinates.`

---

another similar problem is this:

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'loc.type': {
        '$eq': 'Polygon'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'myshape': {
        'type': 'LineString', 
        'coordinates': [
          [
            -11.337890625, 56.31653672211301
          ], [
            13.1396484375, 42.8115217450979
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'loc': {
        '$geoIntersects': {
          '$geometry': '$myshape'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

here in stage 2, I created a complete GeoJson shape (field `myshape`). I also can't use `myshape` as the shape for `$geometry`. here the error I get is: `unknown geo specifier: $geometry: "$myshape"`.

how I can use a field from the current document as value for the fields `$geometry` or `$geometry.coordinates`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using geospatial data from the document field is not supported for [Geospatial Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-queries-1)